# Get SAN Lun Names

Tags: rhel, disk, scsi, san

My storage administrator assigned LUNS for a RHEL 5.10 Server.

Now when I run `/sbin/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/sdN`, it shows:

```
360060160c8803500183327ae00a2e711
```

Now I want to see the exact name, just like the storage administrator assigned, such as:

`DB2_LUN_1`

What am I missing?

The back end storage from EMC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not. From my experience as storage and linux admin I can tell you, DB2_LUN_1 is alias on storage level. You can confirm the unique id  from storage admin which is similar to 360060160c8803500183327ae00a2e711 (well most of the part). if you are using dm-multipath drivers then you can set alias in your `/etc/multipath.conf` file.

`multipath {
    wwid 360060160c8803500183327ae00a2e711
    alias DB2_LUN_1
}`

and then rescan the scsi_host and run `multipath -ll`